# CloudSQL Second Generation -- can't authorize application to access

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-app-engine-python

I'm creating V2 beta instances and I can't add an authorized application to these instances. As you can see, the manage link doesn't even appear.  How can I add an appengine application as authorized? I've had no problem with the first gen instances.

[image]

Further, clicking on Access Control, the UI to add an authorized application doesn't even appear:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question from before App Engine connectivity was supported for Second Generation instances.

Please follow the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine

---

Old answer for posterity:

App Engine connectivity is not yet available for Second Generation instances.
See the limitations noted on the following page:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/introduction#v2

Please also see:
[2nd generation Google cloud SQL - App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413514/2nd-generation-google-cloud-sql-app-engine)

Comment: They should add this limitation to the list of limitations that appears when you are creating the instance :)

Comment: There's a link to the limitations when you create the instance. Do you think that's insufficient?

Comment: It's sufficient. It does say "No App Engine Support" but I'm surprised I missed that yesterday.  Thank you for your responses and kindness, sincerely appreciated. I've been an appengine user for about 8 years.

Comment: Has there been any traction on this?
I think I'm running into this same issue.
I haven't tried going down to 1st Gen yet but would like to know if I actually have to.

Comment: This is an old question from when Cloud SQL Second Generation was in Beta. It no longer applies.