# Google App Engine authorization to Google Cloud SQL Instance (Second Generation)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

When trying to connect my **Google App Engine** to my **Google Cloud SQL Instance** (**Second Generation**), I cannot find the "...***Authorized App Engine applications section***..." (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#PHP_Build_a_starter_application_and_database).

Am I just blind, or does this not exist anymore?
If it doesn't exist, how does one connect a Google App Engine to a Google Cloud SQL (Second Generation)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2nd generation Google cloud SQL - App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413514/2nd-generation-google-cloud-sql-app-engine)

Comment: You can now connect to 2nd gen SQL instances from GAE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413514/2nd-generation-google-cloud-sql-app-engine/36685353#36685353

Answer (score 2):

Please review the [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/introduction#beta-limitations) of Google Cloud SQL Second Generation.

> Because Cloud SQL Second Generation instances are in beta, the following features are not available:

- Service Level Agreement (SLA)
- MySQL 5.5
- MySQL 5.6 is supported.
- **Google App Engine connectivity**. Connectivity is supported for other clients, including Compute Engine, Managed VMs, Container Engine, and your workstation.
- ....

Comment: Thank you guys! Good stuff! So not blind, just eager.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to mention that although Google App Engine connectivity is not yet supported for the Cloud SQL Second Generation like the way is supported for Cloud SQL 1st Gen, however this doesn't mean that you cannot use Cloud SQL 2nd Gen with your App Engine applications.

You can use access control model which is described in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#accesscontrol) as used for other applications. Since IP address of your App Engine application will be not a static address, you will need to authorize `0.0.0.0/0` IP range as an allowed network and use `Allow only SSL connections` feature of the Cloud SQL to allow only SSL connections. [Configure SSL and generate keys and client certificate](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/configure-ssl-instance) for your application and [establish a secure connections using SSL](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php).

Answer (score 0):

Right now, App Engine cannot be used with CloudSQL Gen2. It should be possible once the CloudSQL Gen2 graduate to General Availability but right now, if you need to use it with App Engine, you'll need to stick with CloudSQL v1